# What is the graph of $r^{2} = 16\cos\left(2\theta\right)$ ?.

Tags: calculus

Plotted it on WolframAlpha and [image: this] came up. What do you call this graph?

Answer (score 3):

They're called "lemniscates" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Bernoulli)